# OAuthException from Facebook graph api on calling for valid keywords using numbers

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting `OAUthException` on calling using the below link. It seems to happen only with keyword_list having numbers, and it does not happen for all numbers, the same link works if keyword_list=1000. (in the below link I did not provide the access_token, but I was using the correct access_token)

https://graph.facebook.com/search?keyword_list=1770&type=adkeywordvalid&access_token=

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}
```